# Windows 10 Desktop crashes in endless loop when a certain TIF image is placed on the desktop

Tags: windows, crash, tiff, explorer, libtiff.net

I developed a software that creates tiled TIF images.
A customer reports a TIF file that was created with my software that crashes Windows 10 desktop in an endless loop after it is placed on the desktop.

I don't know what is wrong with this image. I never experienced something like that.

You can download the TIF file for investigation here:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xZFSAGVCaDV2fILf1Eqe3KfsmywWyCSQ

BUT DONT PLACE IT ON YOUR DESKTOP!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When working with large or scientific TIFF images, consider turning of thumbnail previews in Windows Explorer. Also consider excluding those images from antivirus scanning if you know the images are trustworthy.

Comment: Crashes Explorer for me when attempting to render a thumbnail.

Comment: According to the TIFF specification the `RowsPerStrip` field should not be present for tiled images.

Comment: There's one tile (the 63rd if I counted correctly) in the second IFD that seems to be corrupt. Similar to https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/1179

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you know a command line tool to extract the data of that tile easily without coding?

Comment: [tiffcrop](http://www.simplesystems.org/libtiff/man/tiffcrop.1.html) might work. Or use `TileOffsets[t]` and `TileByteCounts[t]` of tile `t` to read the compressed bytes.